# iOS: How to make navigationBar titleView align left

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
UIView *sLineBarView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1,20)];
        [sCustomTitleView addSubview:sLineBarView];
        [sLineBarView TUMMoveToVerticalCenter];
        [sLineBarView release];

        UIImage *sDropBoxImg= [UIImage imageNamed:@"bt_dropdown"];
        UIImageView *sDropDownBox = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: sDropBoxImg];
        [sDropDownBox setFrame: CGRectMake(0,30, 92, 58)];
        [sDropDownBox setAlpha:1.0f];
        sDropDownBox.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        sDropDownBox.tag = kDropBoxTag;

        [sCustomTitleView addSubview:sDropDownBox];
        [sDropDownBox release];

        UIImage *sRightImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gnb_bt_menu"];

        UIButton *sCustomBarItem0 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20,40)];
        [sCustomBarItem0 setBackgroundImage:sRightImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sCustomTitleView addSubview:sCustomBarItem0];
        [sCustomBarItem0 TUMMoveToVerticalCenter];

        sViewController.navigationItem.titleView = sCustomTitleView;
```

I want to navigationBar titleView alignment left but with no success.

How to make navigationBar titleView align left?

fream.x = negative

In my opinion, this is imprecise.(because ios version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase `sCustomTitleView` width and check or you can try this code in `viewDidLoad`-

```
UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,40)];
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
lbl.text = @"My Title";
self.navigationItem.titleView = lbl;
```

Comment: Thank you !!  
Is textAlignment only text setting ??